# C# List of lists issue

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I've got another question with List of lists. Once again, I have the generic matrix class as below.

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
  List<List<T>> matrix;

  public Matrix()
  {
     matrix = new List<List<T>>();
  }

  public void Add(IEnumerable<T> row)
  {
     List<T> newRow = new List<T>(row);
     matrix.Add(newRow);
  }
}

// Test code
Matrix<double> matrix = new Matrix<double>();    
matrix.Add(new List<double>() { 0, 0 });
matrix.Add(new List<double>() { 16.0, 4.0 });
```

I'm reading lines of strings from a text file which contains values with the following format,

4   2

0.5   0.4   0.6   0.1   10.1   11.1   0.5   12.0

The first line specifies the 4x2 matrix size.
The second line needs to be so that first 4 values are in the first column of the matrix and the last four values should be in the second column.
This is dynamic hence the size is not fixed.

Reading the lines and delimiting these lines is sorted. My question is around how to use the Matrix class to store these values. In other words how can I do the elements in a row ?

It should be done so that the matrix will look like,

0.5   10.1

0.4   11.1

0.6   0.5

0.1   12.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you already have?  It looks like it should work?

Comment: The question is around the adding part. Because this is dynamic I don't know how I can achieve matrix.Add(new List<double>() { row elements })

Comment: You already do that in the code - do you mean to add multiple rows at the same time?

Comment: indeed. that is my question. sorry i didnt phrase it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should your matrix dimensions really be mutable? A better alternative might be to pass its dimensions inside constructor and allocate  **arrays** inside the matrix:

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    private readonly T[][] _matrix;

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        _matrix = new T[rows][];
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            _matrix[r] = new T[cols];
    }

    public T this[int r, int c]
    {
        get { return _matrix[r][c]; }
        set { _matrix[r][c] = value; }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it it **does** need to be mutable, you can choose to allocate it "lazy", as needed:

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    private readonly List<List<T>> _matrix;

    public Matrix()
    {
        _matrix = new List<List<T>>();
    }

    public T this[int r, int c]
    {
        get
        {
            ResizeIfNeeded(r, c);
            return _matrix[r][c]; 
        }
        set
        {
            ResizeIfNeeded(r, c);
            _matrix[r][c] = value;
        }
    }

    private void ResizeIfNeeded(int row, int col)
    {
        while (_matrix.Count <= r)
            _matrix.Add(new List<T>());

        var row = _matrix[r];
        while (row.Count <= c)
            row.Add(default(T));
    }
}
```

Note that the second approach might do a lot of allocations if you are populating it sequentially.

I would opt for the first approach (**a fixed size matrix**), since in most cases its dimensions are already known. It is fastest to allocate, and it's safe to use in a multithreaded application.

If you are reading values from a file, setting them through indices should much simpler than instantiating a new list for each row.

Comment: @kuzyt: I forgot to add `set` accessors in my first revision. I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<List<T>> rows)
{
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        Add(row);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
AddRange(new List<double>[] {
   new List<double> { 0.0, 0.0 },
   new List<double> { 16.0, 14.0 } });
```

Comment: it seems that you may have misunderstood my question because i didnt phrase it correctly. The problem is I don't know whats in the text file that is being read. hence the size of the matrix is dynamic.

Comment: You didn't ask about reading files, you asked about lists of lists and how to add them to your matrix.. the solution you gave and I extended deals with any size matrices,  irregular if necessary.. the other answer, doesn't deal with reading either..?

Answer (score 0):

So wou want a ctor that takes 2 parameters, width and values.

```
public Matrix(int width, IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    if (values.Count() % width != 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("values parameter is indivisible by width");

    int last = 0;
    for (int i = width; i <= values.Count(); i += width)
    {
        Add(values.Skip(last).Take(width))
        last = i;
    }

}
```